# build nested tree with angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data in the angular controller like this

```
[
  {name: 'test', parent_id: 0, children_id: 2, id: 1}, 
  {name: 'test', parent_id: 1, children_id: 3, id: 2}, 
  {name: 'test', parent_id: 2, children_id: 0, id: 3}, 
  ...
];
```

can i build nested tree use angular directive by `parent_id` or `children_id`?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can build the tree using parent_id only. You don't even need children_id

Comment: Place your example please

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular [filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) group by in ng-repeat

```js
angular.module('app', ['angular.filter'])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.parents = [{
        name: 'test',
        parent_id: 0,
        children_id: 2,
        id: 1
      }, {
        name: 'test',
        parent_id: 1,
        children_id: 3,
        id: 2
      }, {
        name: 'test',
        parent_id: 2,
        children_id: 0,
        id: 3
      }, {
        name: 'test 2',
        parent_id: 2,
        children_id: 0,
        id: 3
      }


    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">

  <ul ng-repeat="(parent, children) in parents | groupBy: 'parent_id'">
    parent: {{ parent }}
    <li ng-repeat="child in children">
      child: {{ child.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's only two levels deep. What about the rest?

Comment: you can use it again inside d inner ng repeat like this http://jsbin.com/hapeli/2/

Comment: I not really understand how i build a tree use angular-filter. I need build html tree for [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree)